# Anti-concentration inequalities: lower bound on realized second moment

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, large-deviations

Let $X:(\Omega,\Sigma)\rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^d;\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}^d))$ be a Borel-measurable random vector.  What are some general classes of such random vector for which one can give a "lower concentration inequality" of the form:
$$
\mathbb{P}(\|X\|^2>\lambda) \geq \mbox{(insert non-trivial lower bound)}
$$
where $\lambda>0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose e.g. that $X=X_1+\dots+X_n$, where the $X_i$' are independent zero-mean random vectors with $\|X_i\|\le1$ for all $i$. Then the Hoeffding--Azuma inequality (see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azuma%27s_inequality#A_general_form_of_Azuma's_inequality)) yields
$$P(\|X\|>u)\ge1- e^{-(E\|X\|-u)^2/(2n)}$$
for $u\le E\|X\|$.

A number of lower bounds on $P(\|X\|\ge u)$ were obtained by de Acosta A. and Samur J.D. (Infinitely divisible probability measures and the converse Kolmogorov inequality in Banach spaces. Studia Math. 1979. V. 66, 143--160). For instance, a special case, for $p=2$, of their Corollary 3.1 on p. 151 is the following: 
$$P(\|X\|>u)\ge \frac14\,\Big(1-\frac{(u+1)^2+u^2/2}{E\|X\|^2}\Big)$$
for $u>0$, where $X$ is just as above.

Also, in the proof of their Lemma 2.3, de Acosta and Samur showed that, if the $X_i$'s are also symmetric, then 
$$P(\|X\|>u)\ge\frac12\,P(\max_i\|X_i\|>u)
\ge\frac12\,\Big(1-\exp\Big\{-\sum_i P(\|X_i\|>u)\Big\}\Big)$$
for $u>0$.

Comment: Hmm. The Hoeffding-Azuma inequality you quote is not the one in the reference, and is actually wrong as the example $n=1$ and $u=E|X|$ shows. I believe there is a typo also in the reference you give (Bartlett's notes) -  it should be an upper bound, not a lower bound, as the example t=0 (and the proof given there) show.

Comment: @oferzeitouni : Thank you for your comment. This is now corrected.

Comment: How come the Azuma inequality becomes an anti-concentration one? The bound should be a concentration bound around the mean, not a lower bound on the probability to deviate from the mean. Am I wrong?

Comment: @CuriousGuy : The lower bound here is not on the probability to deviate from the mean -- notice the condition $u\le E\|X\|$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer: what is the considered martingale then?

Comment: @CuriousGuy : The martingale is $(E(\|S_k\|\,|\,X_1,\ldots,X_{k-1}))$, where $S_k:=X_1+\cdots+X_k$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your case notice that $\|X\|^2>0$ and so $\mu\triangleq \mathbb{E}[\|X\|^2]>0$.  Thus, for any $\lambda \in \left(0,\mu\right)$ the Cantelli Inequality gives
$$
\Pr(X\ge\lambda)
\ge 1 - \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2 + \lambda^2},
$$
where $\sigma\triangleq \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\|X\|^2 - \mu\right)^2\right]$.

Comment: This is interesting, but it only holds for small $\lambda$...not sure I'm I'm asking for too much...

Comment: $0<\lambda<\mu$?